# C++ Override base member value

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, radix, derived

i have following code:

```
class A
{
public:
    int foo = 0;
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    int foo = 1;
};

int main()
{
    A *a = new B();

    std::cout << a->foo;
    std::getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

output: 0

why does B not override the member foo from A ?

and how to get the desired output of 1 without casting to derived class

Comment: It's not overriding. It's hiding it. You cant have virtual fields, so overriding is not possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290796/override-member-field-in-derived-classes. You could use a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`B::foo` is a completely separate member from `A::foo`. That is why initializing `B::foo` does not update `A::foo`. You would have to do something more like this instead:

```
class
{
public:
    int foo;
    A(int value = 0) : foo(value) {} 
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B() : A(1) {}
};

int main()
{
    A *a = new B();
    std::cout << a->foo;
    delete a;
    std::getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can only *override* `virtual` member-functions.
All other members, be they functions, types or member-variables, can only be *shadowed*.

That means they are not changed at all, but aren't easily accessible without referring to the proper base, using scope-resolution-operator or the like.

So, change to using virtual functions instead of member-variables.

Answer (score 5):

Use a virtual function. You can't have virtual fields, therefore the value you get is for the type of your instance pointer (`A`) and not the true type of what is pointed to (`B`).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    int foo_ = 0;
public:
    virtual int foo() const { return foo_; }
    virtual ~A(){}
};

class B: public A
{
    int foo_ = 1;
public:
    virtual int foo() const { return foo_; }
};

int main()
{
    A *a = new A();
    A *b = new B();

    cout << a->foo() << '\n';
    cout << b->foo() << '\n';
    cin.ignore();

    delete a;
    delete b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you want to use polymorphic behavior you can write a virtual getter method for your member variable "foo" since data members cannot be directly accessed polymorphically.

Your sample code snippet modified below for achieving that-

```
class A
{
    int foo;
public:
    A() { foo = 0; }
    virtual int getFoo() { return foo; }
};

class B: public A
{
   int foo;
public:
    B() { foo = 1; }
    virtual int getFoo() { return foo; }
};

int main()
{
    A *a = new B();

    std::cout << a->getFoo();
    std::getchar();

    return 0;
}
```