# Overriding pointer to base class with pointer to derived class while inheriting

Tags: c++

I'm not sure if the following code is going to do what I expect it to:

```
struct Foo
{
    // Some variables
};

struct Bar : public Foo
{
    // Some more variables
};

struct Baz : public Foo
{
    // Some more variables
};

class ExampleBase
{
    Foo* A;
    int B;
    double C;
};

class ExampleBar : public ExampleBase
{
    Bar* A;
}

class ExampleBaz : public ExampleBase
{
    Baz* A;
}

void DoStuff(ExampleBase& example)
{
    // Does things with the Foo*, doesn't need to know what inherited type it is
}
```

**What happens when I have the same name for a pointer (A), which is derived from the same class, but is redefined in the derived Example classes?**

I've tried templating the example class like this in order to avoid any ambiguity:

```
template <typename T>
class ExampleBase
{
    T* A;
    int B;
    double C;
}
```

And then not deriving any classes from it. When I did this however, I can't get the DoStuff() function to compile. since I want it to accept any of the possible derived types.

Edit: The answers from the possible duplicate explain what happens, but don't solve the issue of a function using the base version

Comment: You cannot "override" member variables. You just keep adding pointers to the resulting object.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @StoryTeller That was my suspicion, hence my attempt to use templates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override member field in derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290796/override-member-field-in-derived-classes)

Comment: *"Does things with the `Foo*`, doesn't need to know what inherited type it is*" screams "virtual functions". Make `DoThings()` a virtual (possibly abstract) member function of `Foo`, override it in `Bar` and `Baz`

Comment: @Slava I have 2 classes which differ only by the derived type of one pointer. I'm trying to reuse as much code as possible, but the function which is using the base class of the pointer is giving me trouble

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That function is a member of a larger class which uses a lot of things that don't exist in Foo. I can't put it inside the struct, and it doesn't need overriding, since it only uses the base components

Comment: I did not ask what you have, I can see that. I am asking what you are trying to achieve. Your approach is wrong.

Comment: and that trouble is? I am afraid that you made your example too abstract such that the actual problem isnt obvious anymore

Comment: @tobi303 The compiler demands an argument list, but I want the function to work for any version of the class

Comment: no idea what you are talking about, `void DoStuff(ExampleBase& example)` has an argument list and it does accept any derivates of `ExampleBase` Cant you show the actual code and the errors you get?

Comment: @tobi303 I meant that this is the error after templating the class.

Comment: Make `DoStuff` be function template.

Comment: what error and what code? Please provide a [mcve] and include the error message in the question

Comment: actually the question you were asking here is answered by the proposed dupe. Maybe you just ask a new question that includes the problematic code (and not something that you think might be the solution)

Comment: What's the difference in behavior between `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz`? Express those differences in the form of virtual functions. Implement `DoStuff` in terms of these virtual functions. This is OOP 101.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a template for to implement `DoStuff`:

```
template<typename T>
void DoStuff(ExampleBase<T>& example)
{
    // Does things with the T*
}
```

Alternatively, you can expose both the template and the polymorphic interface separately:

```
struct ExampleBase
{
    int B;
    double C;
    virtual Foo* getA();
};

template<typename T>
struct ExampleTBase : ExampleBase
{
    T* A;

    Foo* getA() override { return A; }
};

void DoStuff(ExampleBase& example)
{
    // Does things with the getA(), that returns a Foo*
}
```