# Multiple variable types for one var in one class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a class (Cfg) which accepts multiple variable types in one variable. What I've tried doesn't work since I'm declaring it multiple times, how could I fix it?

```
class Cfg {
public:
    std::string name;
    int value;
};

class Cfg {
public:
    std::string name;
    bool value;
};

class Cfg {
public:
    std::string name;
    float value;
};
```

Comment: This question looks similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290796/override-member-field-in-derived-classes

Comment: Fix it by using different classes, or find a recent C++ book, that came out in the last couple of years, and read the description and examples of using a `std::variant`. You should have, by now, a fairly good grasp of how C++ classes and templates work, because these are the fundamental building blocks of the `std::variant` template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant):

```
#include <variant>

class Cfg {
public:
    std::string name;
    std::variant<int, bool, float> value;
};
```

Or,  you might just decide to store everything in a `float`, and convert to `int` or `bool` as needed later on.

Comment: @JJohn Zwinck second time i heard variant today. but its only for c++17?  is there an alternative one for C++11?

Comment: you can just use boost, @Yucel_K

Comment: @JohnZwinck Should you not include `<variant>` and `<string>`?

Comment: @L.F.: Oops, thanks, I included <variant> now instead of <utility>.  I did not include <string> because it's too obvious.

Comment: @JohnZwinck :P XD