# what is data overriding in c++?

Tags: c++

Recently, I face an interview.
The question faced by me is **what is data overriding?** I know how to override the function in C++.

```
class base {
  public:
  int x;
  int y;
}

class der : public base
{
  int x;
  int y;
}
```

please do need full.

Comment: Nothing will be "overridden". `base::x` name will be hidden by `der::x`, but still accessible.

Comment: It is not data overriding but name hiding ([Override member field in derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290796/override-member-field-in-derived-classes)) the struct `der` has both it's own `int x` and the `int x` of the `base` class encapsulated.

Comment: @Evg base class member functions which are overridden are also still accessible.

Answer (score 2):

Data overriding?

There's no such thing.

The base class data are *shadowed* in `der` but they are accessible in `der` using the scope resolution operator `::`, e.g. `base::x`.

When asked a question that's incorrectly posed in an interview, a strong candidate will point out the correct answer tactfully. For very senior hires I tend to ask a nonsense question deliberately to test the softer skills of the candidate.

Comment: "shadowed" or "hidden" are terms I've come across for this