# C++ problems with class inheritance

Tags: c++

I have base class with some variables and functions and multyply child classes. I want to minimaze amount of code required in child classes as much as possible.

Example of my code:

```
#include <iostream>

class base{
public:
   int a = 10;
   int b;
   void print()
   {
      std::cout << a <<std::endl;
   }
};

class child: public base
{
   public:
      int a;
};

int main()
{
    child ch;
    ch.a = 20;
    ch.print();

}
```

As result number 10 was printed, that means base class variable `a` was used, but i need to use child class variable if it exists. So expected output for this example is 20.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override member field in derived classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290796/override-member-field-in-derived-classes)

Comment: Do you know the reason behind inheritance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a significantly major mistake to override variables from the base class in your child class. This is going to bite you back just so amazingly badly.

What is happening is that ch.a is from the child class (the overwritten version), but the print function is part of the base class, so it's going to print that version.

If there's some reason to do this (I can't think of a single one), then you could typecast ch to the base class before assigning. Something like this:

```
(static_cast<base>(ch)).a = 20;
```

But the better choice is to never, never NEVER overload variable names.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to override print and use this->a ?

Comment: No. It would be better to never override variables. Ever. I can't think of any reason why this is ever a good idea.

Comment: @JosephLarson It can be a “good idea” purely because they are distinct scopes, and what I’m doing in `child` shouldn’t be influenced by implementation details of `base`. I’ve got an (admittedly, special) case where I’m inheriting from a class and I need to store a member which is best described as `path`. That’s the perfect name for the member in this context. Alas, the base class *also* has a member of that name. But … who cares? These two members never cross paths. In fact, the base class member is `private` and the only reason I even know of it is by pure chance.

Comment: @JosephLarson i know that overriding variables is not good idea, but i have to declare some variables in child class (it is hard to explain why). Thank you for your answer, it seems like it is just what i need, but `(static_cast<base>(ch)).a = 20;`,  generates an error: `error: expression is not assignable`. I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: never mind, 
` child ch;
    base* bs; 
    bs = &ch;
    bs->a = 20;`
Works fine in my case.

Comment: The warning paragraph cannot be emphasized enough. Having a derived class with another variable of the same name as the base class seems loading a gun, pointing it at your foot, leaning on the trigger and hoping you are not *that* heavy.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I stand by my statement. I personally never (intentionally) override variables. Never. Not in any instance. It happens unintentionally, and when I find it, I fix it. In your use case I would still use a different name. I admit -- private variables I don't even known about are a different story, but never, never, never do I override a variable that is in scope. It's just screaming to become a bug.

Comment: @JosephLarson So you’d chose a *worse* name, making code (even if slightly) *less readable* just as a matter of principle? Overriding names is just a natural consequence of how language functions. That’s why we have scopes: to avoid having to mangle names in our code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Under no circumstances is a lack of being able to come up with an appropriate name a good excuse for overriding variable names. You're free to write code you want. We're programmers. That by definition makes us fairly creative people. Are you really telling me in the circumstance you're considering, "path" is the absolutely only decent variable name? That would be one heck of a unique situation. In my 40 years of programming, I've never encountered a situation where there was only one good name for a variable, unless following a standard.

Comment: @JosephLarson Not even standards; but when following *conventions*, for sure, yes: `path` has few/no exact synonyms. They all have different nuances, which were all also used in the context that I was talking about. So yes, I’m *somewhat* confident that in this particular situation all alternatives (certainly all that I could think of!) were strictly worse. I’m also somewhat confident that this isn’t a unique situation. *Naming is hard*, and there are often fewer good solutions than people carelessly think.

Comment: @KonradRudolph filePath. directoryPath. configPath. You code how you want, but in no circumstances do I find it better to overload a variable name than to just exercise a little creativity. If your class is called Foo, you could call it fooPath. pathOfFoo. I absolutely promise you the number of times I've chased bugs due to unintentional variable name overloading is WAY WAY higher than chasing bugs because I had to be slightly creative on the name.

Comment: @JosephLarson Neither `filePath` nor `directoryPath` or `configPath` would have been correct here (it really was a *generic* path, I was implementing a filesystem layer API). The class was called `Path`. Do you really suggest I called the variable `pathPath`?! In fact, even `fooPath` for a class `Foo` is an objectively *worse* name, since it contains unnecessary, uninformative clutter. There is approximately *zero* chance here of introducing a bug due to overriding the name. By contrast, choosing a different name would have made the code slightly less readable, making bugs more likely.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to minimaze amount of code required in child classes as much as
> possible.

Well, inheritance is just for that, you have a member with name `a` in the base case, so using inheritance you'll already have that member also in the child class, what's the point of declaring new variable with the same name?

Why it won't ever use child class' `a` is because all member functions have implicit `this` pointer as an argument, and the type of `this` is the class for which you have the member function, so in this case `print` function "actual" declaration is

```
void print(base* this);
```

Thus, in `print` function you have a pointer to the `base` class object and that pointer will see only members from that class.

Answer (score 0):

You can overshadow `print` function in child class and use `this` pointer to access `a` of child class there.

```
class child: public base
{
    public:
    int a;
    void print(){
        std::cout << this-> a << '\n';
    }
};
```

Comment: You did not actually *override* `print` method, child class' `print` method **overshadowed** / **hid** base class' `print` method.

Comment: @Ch3steR thanks for pointing out. I did not knew the term overshadow